# avoid exposing reflection in the package API

Tags: api, go, reflection

In Alan Donovan and Brian Kernighan's "The Go programming language" book p333 (section 12.3 Display, a recursive value printer), it is mentioned that

> Where possible, you should avoid exposing reflection in the API of a package. We'll define an unexported function `display` to do the real work of the recursion, and export `Display`, a simple wrapper around it that accepts an `interface{}` parameter.

```
func Display(name string, x interface{}) {
    fmt.Printf("Display %s (%T):\n", name, x)
    display(name, reflection.ValueOf(x))
```

And the `display` function prints different contents depending on the `Kind` of the input reflection value.

I have two questions

1. Why is it better to not expose the reflection in the package API?
2. Why is using an unexposed `display` function considered as not exposing reflection in the API? Don't we still call `reflection.ValueOf()` in `Display`?

I guess I don't know the definition of "exposing reflection in the package API". Does it just refer to the function arguments or both arguments and content? If it's the former case, then there seems no need to define `display` since the signature of `Display` is `x interface{}`. If it's the latter case, why is it better?

Comment: Because reflection is dangerous, slow and much too easy to abuse and misuse.

Comment: But why does it help to hide it? Their examples in the book uses reflection, but hide it in unexported functions. And the exported functions call the unexported functions.

Comment: Because an unexported function is an implementation detail which you now can change. That's basically what they say. If you need to use reflection: At least keep it hidden from the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### In the book's example

In the book's example, it is because the usage of reflection is an implementation detail. You should always try to hide the implementation details, so you may change the implementation at any time without breaking the "public" API of the package. If you export / add something to the API of your package, you have to carry that for the rest of your life (given you don't want to make backward-incompatible API changes, which is really bad in general).

### In general

*"`interface{}` says nothing"* – Rob Pike. Given that, `reflect.Value` says even less. Unless you have a good reason (can't think of any outside of the `reflect` package itself), you shouldn't create public functions that expect `reflect.Value` as their arguments.

Even if you have a "general" function that must take a value of any type, `interface{}` is preferred as then at least the clients can pass what they have as-is, without having to wrap them in `reflect.Value`.